# Show database value mysql with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I have a code like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var iArrayValue = 10000000;
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#example").sevenSegArray({
            digits: 8,
            value: iArrayValue
        });
    });
});
```

How can I change the `iArrayValue` with data from database `mysql`.

Comment: Which kind of server side languaje are you using? Your code snippet is just javascript.

Comment: I'm using PHP as my server side language, in this case I mean 'how can I get variable values from database mysql'?

Answer (score 0):

You need a server side language (i.e. PHP) to connect to DB and query the data for you. Then you can display the data like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var iArrayValue = 10000000;
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#example").sevenSegArray({
            digits: 8,
            value: '<?php echo $iArrayValue; ?>'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using PHP as my server side language, in this case I mean 'how can I get variable values from database mysql'?

Comment: please provide more information like what is the table name, field name and query condition like if by id or if there is single row in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I just want show the "iArrayValue" into a div with ID = example , like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     var iArrayValue = 88888888;
       setInterval(function() {
           $("#example").sevenSegArray({ digits: 8, value: iArrayValue });
        });
      });
```

```html
<body>
<div id="example" style="padding: 0.5em; height: 100px; width: 420px; display: inline-block; background-color: Black;"></div>
</body>
```